# How to use takeUntilDestroyed

Tags: angular

Angular v16 `takeUntilDestroyed()` could replace a custom DestroyService with `takeUntil()`.

When we use a custom service, it is necessary to place takeUntil at the end of the pipe. Is there any recomendation about takeUntilDestroyed?

Answer (score 2):

`takeUntilDestroyed` relies on the new [`DestroyRef`](https://angular.io/api/core/DestroyRef) (and its `onDestroy` method).

`Destroy.onDestroy()` fires every time its injector is destroyed. For example after `ngOnDestroy` after a component is destroyed.

In a service, if it's provided in root, its injector will be the root injector so the `DestroyRef.onDestroy` will never fire. (Or at least not until the app itself gets destroyed)

So keep in mind, `takeUntilDestroyed()` is not a silver bullet to unsubscribe to your observables.
Unsubscribe from your observable responsibly!

Comment: thanks a lot! if a service is provided in the module, and lazy loaded module applied, if a module will be changed, so takeUntilDestroyed will work?

Comment: Unfortunately, you did not mention, should it be placed as a first item in a pipe or the last..

Comment: The place doesn't matter much but I like it in first position (for readability);